# HTTP realtime audio streaming server

Tags: python, http, flask, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

As a proof-of-concept I need to create a HTTP server which on GET request should start continuous stream of non-encoded/non-compressed audio data - WAV, PCM16. Let's assume the audio data are chunks of  4096 randomly generated mono audio samples @44.1kHz sampling rate.

What should I put in the HTTP response header in order to browser on the other end start a player in its UI for the user to listen in realtime?

I was reading about "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", "multipart", mimetype="audio/xwav", but still not sute what and how to use...

Great would be if someone can give me an exact example on Python/Flask because I'm not so confident with the web development.

PS1: Replacing HTTP server with an embedded device with limited HW power will be the next stage after the PoC.

PS2: This is the code which actually works and sends an WAV chunk as a single HTTP response:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response,render_template
import pyaudio
import audio_processing as audioRec

app = Flask(__name__)

def genHeader(sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels, samples):
    datasize = samples * channels * bitsPerSample // 8
    o = bytes("RIFF",'ascii')                                               # (4byte) Marks file as RIFF
    o += (datasize + 36).to_bytes(4,'little')                               # (4byte) File size in bytes excluding this and RIFF marker
    o += bytes("WAVE",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) File type
    o += bytes("fmt ",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Format Chunk Marker
    o += (16).to_bytes(4,'little')                                          # (4byte) Length of above format data
    o += (1).to_bytes(2,'little')                                           # (2byte) Format type (1 - PCM)
    o += (channels).to_bytes(2,'little')                                    # (2byte)
    o += (sampleRate).to_bytes(4,'little')                                  # (4byte)
    o += (sampleRate * channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(4,'little')  # (4byte)
    o += (channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(2,'little')               # (2byte)
    o += (bitsPerSample).to_bytes(2,'little')                               # (2byte)
    o += bytes("data",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Data Chunk Marker
    o += (datasize).to_bytes(4,'little')                                    # (4byte) Data size in bytes
    return o

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHUNK = 102400 #1024
RATE = 44100
bitsPerSample = 16 #16
CHANNELS = 1
wav_header = genHeader(RATE, bitsPerSample, CHANNELS, CHUNK)

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE, input=True, input_device_index=10,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
# print "recording..."

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index2.html')

@app.route('/audio_unlim')
def audio_unlim():
    # start Recording
    def sound():

        #while True:
        #    data = wav_header + stream.read(CHUNK)
        #    yield(data)
        data = wav_header + stream.read(CHUNK)
        yield(data)

    return Response(sound(),
                    mimetype="audio/x-wav")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True,port=5000)
```

and the index2.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{ url_for('audio_unlim') }}" type="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio
</body>
</html>
```

What to change in order to achieve continuous stream of chunks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Audio Livestreaming with Python & Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079338/audio-livestreaming-with-python-flask)

Comment: @noslenkwah, no this does not solve my problem. The link you've refer to is about how to send one chunk of data as one shot with a single HTTP response. I want to to have continuous stream of audio data may be by using "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" or "Content-Transfer-Encoding: multipart". Still not sure the HTTP sequence diagram how to do that and what to type in the HTTP headers and MIME to notify browser to start corresponding player to interpret the RIFF data in the WAV header correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I've made a kind of workaround with the following code (without any index.html) and it works fine without any interruptions:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response,render_template
import pyaudio
import audio_processing as audioRec

app = Flask(__name__)

def genHeader(sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels, samples):
    datasize = 10240000 # Some veeery big number here instead of: #samples * channels * bitsPerSample // 8
    o = bytes("RIFF",'ascii')                                               # (4byte) Marks file as RIFF
    o += (datasize + 36).to_bytes(4,'little')                               # (4byte) File size in bytes excluding this and RIFF marker
    o += bytes("WAVE",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) File type
    o += bytes("fmt ",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Format Chunk Marker
    o += (16).to_bytes(4,'little')                                          # (4byte) Length of above format data
    o += (1).to_bytes(2,'little')                                           # (2byte) Format type (1 - PCM)
    o += (channels).to_bytes(2,'little')                                    # (2byte)
    o += (sampleRate).to_bytes(4,'little')                                  # (4byte)
    o += (sampleRate * channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(4,'little')  # (4byte)
    o += (channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(2,'little')               # (2byte)
    o += (bitsPerSample).to_bytes(2,'little')                               # (2byte)
    o += bytes("data",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Data Chunk Marker
    o += (datasize).to_bytes(4,'little')                                    # (4byte) Data size in bytes
    return o

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHUNK = 1024 #1024
RATE = 44100
bitsPerSample = 16 #16
CHANNELS = 1
wav_header = genHeader(RATE, bitsPerSample, CHANNELS, CHUNK)

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE, input=True, input_device_index=10,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
# print "recording..."

@app.route('/audio_unlim')
def audio_unlim():
    # start Recording
    def sound():
        data = wav_header
        data += stream.read(CHUNK)
        yield(data)
        while True:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            yield(data)

    return Response(sound(), mimetype="audio/x-wav")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True,port=5000)
```

I've just started with sending a WAV header, but the size written there is veeery big number telling the player to wait veeery big buffer of data. Until the "end" player plays the coming chunks of data without any problem (no WAV headers anymore just chunks of audio data!). This is without any "Transfer-encoding: chunked" or anything else! Just set the mimetype to "audio/x-wav". And the HTTP response is extremely simple as follows:

[image]

Comment: import audio_processing as audioRec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'audio_processing'

Answer (score 3):

Chunked transfer encoding is recommended, since the resource has an indefinite length.  Without it, you would need to specify a `Content-Length` header.  Older clients used to not be able to handled chunked transfer encoding well, so the old hack was to either leave out the `Content-Length` header entirely (HTTP/1.0 behavior), or to specify a very large (effectively infinite) length.

As for `Content-Type`, you can use `audio/vnd.wav;codec=1` for regular PCM.

Be sure to set `preload="none"` on your `<audio>` element so that the browser doesn't try to buffer things ahead of time.

Comment: can you tell me what to change where in the code above? I've updated my issue with the exact code I'm using...

Comment: @valioiv No, sorry, I'm no Python guy.  Please do set the correct `Content-Type` though as I suggested.  (Right now, you have `audio/x-wav`, which might work, but who knows.)  I imagine Flask is going to handle chunked transfer encoding for you?

Comment: I assume, Flask handles chunked transfer by passing an iterator into Response

Answer (score 0):

Found another more simple and suitable for me solution with help of [`ffmpeg-python`](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

```py
from flask import Flask, Response
import ffmpeg

app = Flask(__name__)

RATE = 44100

@app.route('/')
def audio_unlim():
    """Audio streaming generator"""
    print ("Running proc!")
    proc = (ffmpeg
            # Use alsa device 1
            .input("hw:1", format="alsa", ar=RATE)
            # Set output format to wav
            .output("pipe:", format="wav")
            # Configure ffmpeg for steaming
            .global_args("-re")
            # Get subprocess to comunicate with its stdout
            .run_async(pipe_stdout=True, quiet=True, overwrite_output=True)
    )
    def sound():
        # Get 44 bytes of header first
        yield proc.stdout.read(44)
        try:
            while True:
                yield proc.stdout.read(16)
        finally:
            proc.kill()
            proc.wait()

    return Response(sound(), mimetype="audio/x-wav")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=False, port=5000, use_reloader=False)
```

You do not need to take care of header format here - ffmpeg will do all the work for you. Additionally, you may want to use another format. I did not manage to, but I believe, we can.

Answer (score -1):

> ### Server-side Streaming Technologies
>
> In order to stream live audio, you will need to run specific streaming software on your
>   server.
>
> ---
>
> - **SHOUTcast**
>
>   *SHOUTcast* is a cross-platform proprietary technology for streaming
>     media. Developed by Nullsoft, it allows digital audio content in MP3
>     or AAC format to be broadcast. For web use, SHOUTcast streams are
>     transmitted over HTTP.
>
>   **Note**: [SHOUTcast URLs may require a semi-colon to be appended to
>     them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743279/how-could-i-play-a-shoutcast-icecast-stream-using-html5).
>
> ---
>
> - **Icecast**
>
>   The *Icecast* server is an open source technology for streaming
>     media. Maintained by the Xiph.org Foundation, it streams Ogg
>     Vorbis/Theora as well as MP3 and AAC format via the SHOUTcast
>     protocol.
>
>   **Note**: SHOUTcast and Icecast are among the most established and
>     popular technologies, but there are many more streaming media systems
>     available.
>
> ---

**Edit**

I'm a Django guy and I've been testing things, and, seems, it works fine, only needs some proper file management and stuff. I've been working with mp3, but you can work with anything browsers have support for.

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def stream(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(streamer(200000) ,content_type='audio/mp3')

def streamer(pointer):
    with open('media/Indila - Parle A Ta Tete.mp3', 'rb') as file:
        file.seek(pointer)
        for chunk in iter(lambda: file.read(4096), b''):
            yield chunk
#the connection is open until this iterator hasn't finished
```

Comment: It would be hard, even impossible, to run complex technologies like SHOUTcast and Icecast on the embedded device later on. I'd like to see minimalistic example with exact HTTP response headers and whatever metadata is needed to notify Chrome browser to start its audio player for WAV PCM16 and play it continuously.

Comment: Then, you're gonna have to plunge into the low level browsers's [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), or maybe make use of a pretty famous JS library like [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/).

Comment: @ArthurGrigoryan This answer is not correct at all.  What valioiv is looking for is doable, and is in fact very similar to the way SHOUTcast/Icecast work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I thought audio needs to be fragmented before streaming as it is with video, I suppose.